# How do I get this shower head holder off the wall?

Tags: repair, shower, hole, screwdriver

Please see images below. The whole unit is loose and needs tightening but I have no idea on how I remove it ? Can anyone help?

I’ve inserted a screw driver into the small hole and was advised that this should come off but nothing happens when I put the screwdriver in.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: When you put the screwdriver in the hole  did you push it in firmly while pulling on the shower head? Have you tried turning the screwdriver in the hole?  Can you see in the hole? Have tried turning the whole unit counterclockwise?

Comment: Have you looked in the hole with a strong light? It might use an Allen key rather than a slotted screw...

Answer (score 1):

These can definitely be challenging. Some manufacturers use a Philips screw, while others use an Allen screw. At least, these are the 2 most common types. Either way, remember they're used in an area that is damp and some corrosion may build up in the slots or hole, so you may need to use a little more upward or downward force, opposed to turning force, into the set screw than usual when turning.

So, if you only tried using a Philips screwdriver, try using a variety of metric and standard Allen wrenches.

Good luck!